# iOS Enterprise account: Distribute app using itunes

Tags: ios, deployment, enterprise

I am not able to install the app using itunes

Following are the things that i have done

1) Made a distribution certificate
2) Made an app id matching to xcode file
3) made the provisional file
4) Install it in xcode
5) Archive the file
6) Save for inhouse developement
7) Above mob provisional was selected 
8) App was saved as an ipa file
9) Drag it on itunes
10) SYnc
11) App not installed is the error that i am getting on the Pad not on itunes

Answer (score 0):

iTunes only works on the computer they synced with. You are better off using OTA (over the air) distribution. Check [this site](http://testflightapp.com/dashboard/) to get started using an OTA service

Comment: Didnt get you. I am using the same computer to sync.

Comment: Did you select the option to sync applications with the device? also, consider OTA to avoid dealing with iTunes. Makes distribution much easier.